# In Azure DevOps portal how to query list of tasks whose Completed effort is modified today

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps portal how to query list of work items whose "Completed effort" is modified today. Actually I'm trying to query list of work items my team members have worked today and email them to my manager.

I'm able to query list of work items "modified" by users today, but I do not want to retrieve a work item if it's completed effort is not modified and some other filed is modified.

Comment: Hi Did you try out below workaround, how did it go?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT : I was busy and sick so couldn't try below work around yet. As per Stackoverflow guidelines we are not supposed to post thank you +1 messages also. I'll give it a try but not sure if I can do it sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it cannot be done directly. There is not such a filter of completed effort change.

However, there is a workaround to achieve this. Check below:

1, Add a custom field of Date type(see below `Modified Date` field). Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops#add-a-custom-field) for detailed steps.

[image]

2, Create a rule: Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps:

Condtions: When change was made to `Completed work` field.

[image]

Action: Set the customized `Modified Date` field to the `Changed Date`

[image]

3,Then you can add `Modified Date` filter in your Query. See below query, only the work items whose `completed effort` filed is modified today will be returned:

[image]

Another workaround is to use work item tracking Rest api. This is a little complicated:

1, First call [Wiql rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get all the work items of your current query.

2, Second loop through the returned work items and call [Updates rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), Then filter those work items whose completed effort field has new value.